# Display Duplication API frame buffer 2 bytes (not pixels) shorter than expected with a 1366 horizontal resolution

Tags: c++, duplicates, display

I am writing a program to capture the desktop using the Display Duplication API but I am having an issue that even GPT-4 can't gets it's head around where if the horizontal resolution is not a multiple of 4 like 1366x768, a line in the BGRA frame buffer will be 2 BYTES shorter than expected, I'm pretty sure the horizontal resolution must be a multiple of 4 PIXELS (16 bytes) but the frame buffer is taking off 2 BYTES per line when it should be taking off 2 PIXELS (8 bytes) to align with the 16 byte boundary.

I need to remove the alpha channel so I'm using this loop to convert to RGB but the RowPitch parameter of the D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE is already equal to output.width * 4 where output.width is 1366 so does not correct for the alignment

```
unsigned char* dstPtr = output.RGBOut;
const unsigned char* srcPtr = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mappedResource.pData);
for(int y = 0; y < output.height; ++y){
    for(int x = 0; x < output.width; ++x){
        dstPtr[0] = srcPtr[0]; // Blue
        dstPtr[1] = srcPtr[1]; // Green
        dstPtr[2] = srcPtr[2]; // Red
        srcPtr += 4;
        dstPtr += 3;
    }
    srcPtr += mappedResource.RowPitch - output.width * 4;
}
```

These images are 16x16 pixels expanded to 256x256 with 1 pixel wide vertical white stripes covering the right half to show the effect this alignment error has on the pixels where the second picture is the corrupt output.

[image: A small sample of a test image with white vertical stripes on the right half where each stripe is 1 pixel wide]
[image: The above image after being processed showing the 2 byte alignment issue]

I am not sure how I should account for this alignment issue and would prefer if it can be vectorizable which it currently is not with the last line adjusting the source pointer inside the outer loop.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure the horizontal resolution must be a multiple of 4." The scan line size in bytes is a multiple of 4. The pixel count is not a factor.

Comment: So a 32 bit image should never need padding and the resolution shouldn't matter, seems odd how this resolution doesn't align with 4 bytes.

Comment: So this is utterly perplexing, i have found the actual extent of the actual image data in the process memory because the 0 0 0 255 pattern of black BGRA is very recognisable and the frame buffer comes to 4198400 bytes where the actual frame data should be 1366x768x4=4196352 bytes so the image data in memory is 2048 bytes bigger than it should be which comes to an extra 1.49926 bytes per line which absolutely makes no freaking sense in the history of the universe!

Comment: Now after making an interlaced black and white horizontal striped frame i can count the number of bytes in each line in memory and it comes to 5464 bytes per line which is exactly 1366x4 so i don't know what is going wrong!